# Xcode UI not updating with latest Firebase Values

Tags: ios, swift, firebase

I have an app that uses Firebase to fetch and store data. In my ViewDidLoad I am using:

```
    fullnameTextField.text = currentUser.fullName
```

where currentUser.fullname references the dictionary. Now, I have a function to update this info in Firebase:

```
    @IBAction func saveFullNameDidTap(_ sender: Any) {
            let ref = DatabaseReference.users(uid: currentUser.uid).reference().child("fullName")
            if let fullName = fullnameTextField.text {
            ref.setValue(fullName)
            }
            fullnameTextField.resignFirstResponder()
            fullnameSaveButton.isHidden = true
            alert(title: "", message: "Name Successfully Changed", buttonTitle: "OK")
        }
```

This does indeed change the info in Firebase but when I reload that particular page, the data in that field reverts back to the old value. If I re-build the app, it will be updated with the correct info though. How do I get the latest data into the field each time it is changed?

Answer (score 0):

I think you should reload the view with new values using:

```
view.setNeedsDisplay()
```

Answer (score 0):

This seems to work

```
    @IBAction func saveFullNameDidTap(_ sender: Any) {
            let ref = DatabaseReference.users(uid: currentUser.uid).reference().child("fullName")
            let fullName = fullnameTextField.text
            ref.setValue(fullName)
            currentUser.fullName = fullName!
            fullnameTextField.resignFirstResponder()
            fullnameSaveButton.isHidden = true
            alert(title: "", message: "Name Successfully Changed", buttonTitle: "OK")
        }
```